# Why is the size of the bitmap file 320x240 9730byte?

Tags: bitmap

My environment:

```
CentOS6.5 (32bit)
ext4 file system
Intel Fortran v14.0.1
```

I am trying to read a bmp formatted file.

[image: the BMP file]

I studied about bmp format. There is 14 byte of BITMAPFILEHEADER and, 40 byte of BITMAPINFOHEADER.

The width and height of the image is 320x240. 
The color depth of the image is 1-bit.

From my calculation, the size of the bmp file is

```
14 + 40 + 320x240/8 = 9654.
```

However, the actual size is 9730.

What is the cause of the difference (9730 - 9654 = 76)? Is this because of the sector size of the file?

---

The following is my code (Fortran) to print header info.

```
implicit none
type :: t_bmpFileHeader
  sequence 
  integer(2) :: bfType
  integer(4) :: bfSize
  integer(2) :: bfReserved1
  integer(2) :: bfReserved2
  integer(4) :: bfOffBits
end type t_bmpFileHeader

type(t_bmpFileHeader) :: fheader

open(10, file='test.bmp', form='binary', status='unknown')
read(10) fheader

print *, fheader%bfSize
print *, fheader%bfOffBits

close(10)

end
```

The output (bfSize and bfOffBits) is

```
9730
130
```

---

Following is the output of `identify -verbose test.bmp`.

```
Image: test.bmp
Format: BMP (Microsoft Windows bitmap image)
Class: PseudoClass
Geometry: 320x240+0+0
Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
Type: Bilevel
Base type: Bilevel
Endianess: Undefined
Colorspace: Gray
Depth: 1-bit
Channel depth:
gray: 1-bit
Channel statistics:
  Pixels: 76800
  Gray:
    min: 0 (0)
    max: 1 (1)
    mean: 0.0985417 (0.0985417)
    standard deviation: 0.298046 (0.298046)
    kurtosis: 5.25731
    skewness: 2.69394
    entropy: 0.464356
Colors: 2
Histogram:
   69232: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
   7568: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)
Colormap entries: 2
Colormap:
     0: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
     1: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)
Rendering intent: Perceptual
Chromaticity:
  red primary: (0.64,0.33)
  green primary: (0.3,0.6)
  blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
  white point: (0.3127,0.329)
Background color: gray(255)
Border color: gray(223)
Matte color: gray(189)
Transparent color: gray(0)
Interlace: None
Intensity: Undefined
Compose: Over
Page geometry: 320x240+0+0
Dispose: Undefined
Iterations: 0
Compression: Undefined
Orientation: Undefined
Properties:
  date:create: 2015-01-18T07:39:32+09:00
  date:modify: 2015-01-18T07:39:32+09:00
  signature: 15df8571403f34fba791b56123e6923fc88fcc9f24e57a24aad152c651f3a55d
Artifacts:
  filename: test.bmp
  verbose: true
Tainted: False
Filesize: 9.73KB
Number pixels: 76.8K
Pixels per second: 3.0130237EB
User time: 0.000u
Elapsed time: 0:01.000
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-4 Q16 i686 2015-01-17 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Comment: This is not really a programming question...

Comment: @walther I would like to make a program to read bmp file. That's the reason why I ask.

Comment: The fact I'd like to develop a software for reading biofeedback doesn't mean I can ask medical questions here... :) It's more suitable for http://superuser.com/ , because the question itself isn't about programming at all... When you run into problems with implementing something and you'd have a code to show, then it's a programming question.

Comment: Make sure of the [actual subformat used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format). Check the "offset" BMP header field. The offset + 9600 should be the same as the actual size.

Comment: (And no; `ls` and similar will report the size of the file data itself; not any associated filesystem/hardware overheads.)

Comment: @user2864740 Thank you very much. I'll check.

Comment: @sevenOfNine: The image you have provided is a PNG, not a BMP.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: perhaps that's just because SO does not accept BMPs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated bmp file, which was converted to PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each scanline of the pixel data is rounded up an even multiple of 4 bytes.  Make sure you take that into account, as uneven widths will take more bytes than you are expecting (in this particular example, 320 is an even multiple of 4, though).

Bitmaps with a bit depth <= 8 have a color table, which you are ignoring. So there is another 8-1024 bytes, depending on the bit depth and compression type.

There are other header fields and alignment padding that may be present, depending on the bitmap type (there are many options available that influence how data is packed).

These extra details would easily account for the extra bytes you are missing, so you have to pay attention to what the bitmap header actually tells you.

Read the following for more details:

[BMP file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

[Bitmap Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183391.aspx)

[BITMAPFILEHEADER structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374.aspx)

[BITMAPINFO structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183375.aspx)

[BITMAPINFOHEADER structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed reply. I could study a lot on the BMP so that I can read it using Fortran.